# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo- super()

Tags: android

```
public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker, this, true);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        InputFilter inputFilter = new NumberPickerInputFilter();
        mNumberInputFilter = new NumberRangeKeyListener();
        mIncrementButton = (NumberPickerButton) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        mIncrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mIncrementButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        mIncrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);
        mDecrementButton = (NumberPickerButton) findViewById(R.id.decrement);
        mDecrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDecrementButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        mDecrementButton.setNumberPicker(this);

        mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
        mText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        mText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {inputFilter});
        mText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        if (!isEnabled()) {
            setEnabled(false);
        }

        mStart = DEFAULT_MIN;
        mEnd = DEFAULT_MAX;
    }
```

Hey people,I am aware that `Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo` is caused due to super(). Please help me for the same. Please provide me with the same.I am not really sire how to create to create super() for this class.

Comment: may be `super(context, attrs,defStyle);
`

Comment: I have tried it earlier. The ctor is undefined

Comment: can you provide the class declaration too? what does this class extend or implement?

Answer (score 0):

```
super(this, attrs,0);
```

and the code is working